# opening a py script from an html

Tags: python, html

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-5">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hola mi Lunita</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2 class="question">Un 2024 juntitos y 1 CH de amor?</h2>
        <img class="gif" alt="gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/FTGah7Mx3ss04PcasF/giphy.gif"/>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="yes-btn">Yes</button>
            <button class="no-btn">No</button>
            <button onclick="openDrawingPage()">Bonus Lunita</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="drawing.py"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this drawing.py

```
from turtle import *
import colorsys

speed(0)
bgcolor("black")
h=0

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(18): 
        c=colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h,0.9,1)
        color(c) 
        h+=0.005
        rt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        lt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        rt (180)
    circle(40, 24)

penup()
goto(0, -230)  # Move to the center of the canvas
pendown()
color("white") # You can choose any color for the text
write("Te amo mi Lunita hermosa", align="center", font=("Calibri", 20, "normal"))

done ()
```

How do i make the drawing.py file to run when the button (Bonus Lunita) is used, i want it to open another page and the python script runs

I dont seem to link the drawing.py to the index.html

Comment: Yea... You can't run python in the browser, at least not natively. There are some projects to tackle this but that's outside the scope of this question. Where did you get the idea you can run python in the browser

Comment: where do you expect this Turtle to draw its stuff

Comment: if you want to draw on another page why include it on this page

Comment: A Python application displaying graphics on a native desktop GUI is far removed from a web page.  Don't pursue that.  Instead, take a look at https://github.com/bjpop/js-turtle which appears to implement the same thing in a web environment with HTML Canvas and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You basically can't do that. It is impossible to run a python file from a HTML site. You can't open a file on **your** computer on a *site* aka *the file in the web servers*. Even if you managed to get this python file on the serers, you still can't run it on people's computers or even display it on your site with python. Take a look on [this module](https://github.com/bjpop/js-turtle), it is basically turtle but in javascript, as @erik258 pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *
import colorsys

speed(0)
bgcolor("black")
h = 0

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(18)
        c =colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h,  0.9, 1)
        color(c)
        h += 0.005
        rt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        lt(90)
        circle(150-j*6,90)
        rt(180)
    circle(40,24)


    done()
```